# file upload multier MulterError: Unexpected field

Tags: javascript, node.js

Not able to upload image in MongoDB database using NodeJS
Middleware fieldName and key name is also same still not working. no solution on internet

server.js

```
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import multer from "multer";

export const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

let upload = multer()
app.use(upload.array())
app.use("/",routLog,router)
app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    db()
    console.log(`Server is Runing on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`)
})
```

blogroute.js

```
import { fileUploder } from "../middelware/fileUploder.js";
export const blogRouter = Router()
blogRouter.post('/:user/create-post', fileUploder.single("file"), blogsController.createPos
```

This middleware file fileUplad.js which is use to store in upload folder and then from that will store in MongoDB in buffer ferment

```
import { randomBytes } from "crypto";
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './upload',
    filename: async (req, file, callback) => {
        return await randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
            const fileInfo = {
                filename: filename,
                bucketName: "upload"
            };
            resolve(fileInfo);
        })
    }   
})

export const fileUploder = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 2000 },
    fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
        allowedFileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
        if (file.mimetype == 'jpg' || file.mimetype == 'jpeg' || file.mimetype == 'png', file.mimetype == 'gif') {
            return cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb("Invalid file type. Only JPEG, PNG and GIF file are allowed.")
        }
    }
})
```

[image]

````
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (/mnt/ssd/BlogProject/backendapi/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
    at Multipart.<anonymous> (/mnt/ssd/BlogProject/backendapi/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:107:7)
    at Multipart.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at HeaderParser.cb (/mnt/ssd/BlogProject/backendapi/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:358:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (/mnt/ssd/BlogProject/backendapi/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:162:20)
    at SBMH.ssCb [as _cb] (/mnt/ssd/BlogProject/backendapi/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:394:37)
    at feed (/mnt/ssd/BlogProject/backendapi/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:248:10)
    at SBMH.push (/mnt/ssd/BlogProject/backendapi/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:104:16)
    at Multipart._write (/mnt/ssd/BlogProject/backendapi/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:567:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)```
````

Comment: Tangential: `file.mimetype == 'png', file.mimetype == 'gif'` won't do what you want.

Comment: Tangential: Isn't `filename` supposed to be a filename? You're resolving to an object.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example :

```
  let multer = require('multer');
  let multerImage = multer().single('file');

  function uploadAvatar(req, res) {


    let phone = data.phoneNumber;


    multerImage(req, res, () => {


        let file = req.file;

        if (isUndefined(file))
            return Json.builder(Response.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

        let {
            fileUrl
        } = File.validationAndWriteFile(file.buffer, Util.getFileFormat(file.originalname));

        Update.img(phone, fileUrl, result => {
            if (!result)
                return Json.builder(Response.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

            Json.builder(Response.HTTP_OK);
        });

    });

  }
```